# SQL: SEL item A from column A from table where item B in column B is higher

Tags: sql, teradata

I got following rows for the same customer_id in sql table.

```
customer id.  outstanding_balance    delinquency_bucket    status_code 
123                $50                    4                      A
123                $100                   6                      Z
345                $70                    3                      A
345                $60                    4                      A
```

The result should be one row for each customer_id. 
For each customer_id, i need to get maximum delinquency bucket and status code associated with maximum delinquency bucket, and also need to summarize all outstanding balance.

The result should be like:

```
customer id.  outstanding_balance    delinquency_bucket    status_code 
123                $150                    6                     Z
345                $130                    4                     A
```

Can anybody help with the sql code?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Below query is in oracle, please tag the database you are using, so that can modify the query accordingly,

```
select customer_id, '$' || sum(replace(outstanding_balance, '$', '')), 
max(delinquency_bucket), max(status_code) 
from table group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using Teradata, could you please modify the query accordingly. BTW, status_code is non-numerical value, I'm wondering why you use max() here?